# Can I refer to cells in a tabular?

Tags: tables, cross-referencing

I have a `tabular` table, and in my text I want to refer to cells in the table. One way is to superscript the cell content:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lrr}\hline
This & $99^a$ & $1.23$\\
That & $22$ & $3.45$\\
The Other & $69^b$ & $9.99$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center} 
\end{table}

I enjoyed `This' (a) and `The Other` (b).
```

but then if I rearrange the rows of the table the letters are out of alphabetical order. `\label` just uses the table number as reference so that doesn't work.

Maybe there's a better stylistic device to do this...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can modify `\@currentlabel` to be whatever you want and then use `\label`-`\ref` as usual. `\@currentlabel` is used as the reference component when using `\ref`. The command `\speciallabel{<stuff>}{<label>}` in the MWE below modifies `\@currentlabel` to be `<stuff>` and sets the label to `<label>`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\speciallabel}[2]{% \speciallabel{<stuff>}{<label>}
  \edef\@currentlabel{#1}\label{#2}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lrr}\hline
    This & $99^a$\speciallabel{a}{this} & $1.23$\\
    That & $22$ & $3.45$\\
    The Other & $69^b$\speciallabel{b}{theother} & $9.99$\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

I enjoyed `This' (\ref{this}) and `The Other` (\ref{theother}).
\end{document}
```

There was no request for [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) accommodation.

---

For an automated counter-style reference, consider the following version of `\speciallabel{<label>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{spcounter}\renewcommand{\thespcounter}{\alph{spcounter}}
\newcommand{\speciallabel}[1]{% \speciallabel{<label>}
  \refstepcounter{spcounter}\textsuperscript{\thespcounter}\label{#1}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lrr}\hline
    This & $99\speciallabel{this}$ & $1.23$\\
    That & $22$ & $3.45$\\
    The Other & $69\speciallabel{theother}$ & $9.99$\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

I enjoyed `This' (\ref{this}) and `The Other` (\ref{theother}).
\end{document}
```

Note that this will have the counter increment throughout the document. However, it can also be made to reset at the start of the `table` (or `tabular`) environment, if needed.

Comment: Does exactly the job. I've also realised I might want to refer to several cells with the same label at some point, saying something like "`three cells (labelled \ref{large}) were significantly large and two (\ref{small}) very small`". But that's probably another question...

Comment: @Spacedman: Then an automated solution might interfere with this. However, my first solution provides a manual way of selecting the reference. If need be, you can combine the two by using a reference as the argument to `\speciallabel{\ref{..}}{<label>}`. Perhaps a renewed syntax that allows a mix of the two is in order. I'll think of something...

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\newcounter{mycount}
\renewcommand\themycount{%
\arabic{mycount}%
\ifcase\value{mycount}%
th\or st\or nd\or rd\else th\fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{>{\refstepcounter{mycount}\themycount}lc}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Step}  & Comments \\
 & a \\
\label{here} & b \\
 & c \\
 & d 
\end{tabular}
\caption{}\label{}
\end{table}


blah blah see the \ref{here} row.
\end{document}
```

Comment: That references rows, I'd really like to do cells, and I would prefer to have a mark in the cell (alpha or numeric) so the reader can eyeball it quickly. I need to pick out two or three cells in a table of about twenty numbers.

Comment: It doesn't _really_ reference rows (there is no TeX group that corresponds to a row) it just references the first cell, if you put `>{\refstepcounter{mycount}}` into every column the counter would increment and be referenceable in all cells. You can have any mark you want I just used `\themycount` above but you can have nothing or put it in a `\textsuperscript` or whatever.

Comment: or do you mean you only want the counter to increment for the cells you reference (that's also possible but I'm offline for an hour or two from  now) ping a comment here I'll pick it up later