# Missing $ inserted in equation environment

Tags: tables, cross-referencing

I am having some trouble with the table that can be found below. When compiling, I am getting the error *Missing $ inserted*, here:

```
I&CW& 
\begin{equation}\label{eq:jammer_CW}
i[n]=A_J\exp(j2\pi f_JnT_s)\qquad\quad
\end{equation}
&$A_{J}$, $f_{J}$ \\[1ex]
\hline
```

While when adding the $ symbol, like this:

```
I&CW& 
\begin{equation}\label{eq:jammer_CW}
$i[n]=A_J\exp(j2\pi f_JnT_s)$\qquad\quad
\end{equation}
&$A_{J}$, $f_{J}$ \\[1ex]
\hline
```

I get another error: *you can't use eqno' in restricted horizontal mode*

Does anybody have an idea of how to solve this issue? Thank you so much in advance!

Here, the whole table:

```
\begingroup
% A table with adjusted row and column spacings
% \setlength sets the horizontal (column) spacing
% \arraystretch sets the vertical (row) spacing
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt} % Default value: 6pt
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % Default value: 1
\begin{table}[h]
\small
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Class&Type&Baseband model&Design parameters\\
\hline
I&CW& 
\begin{equation}\label{eq:jammer_CW}
i[n]=A_J\exp(j2\pi f_JnT_s)\qquad\quad
\end{equation}
&$A_{J}$, $f_{J}$ \\[1ex]
\hline
II&Single Chirp& \begin{equation}\label{eq:jammer_ST}
i[n] = A_{J}\exp(j2\pi T_{s}\sum_{j=0}^{n}f_{J}[j])\qquad \end{equation}&$A_{J}$, $T_{sweep}$, $\Delta f$ \\[1ex]
\hline
II&Pulsed Jammer&Equation \ref{eq:jammer_ST} with $\Delta f > BW$&$A_{J}$, $T_{sweep}$, $\Delta f$\\[1ex]
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Classification of the implemented jamming baseband signal models, according to \citerd{Morales-Ferre2020}.}
\label{tab:signalmodels}
\end{table}
% The \begingroup ... \endgroup pair ensures the separation
% parameters only affect this particular table, and not any
% sebsequent ones in the document.
\endgroup
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot put an equation environment inside a tabular cell with a column type other than `p`. Use inline math instead and preceed the content with `\displaystyle` which changes the math style to display mode, like `$\displaystyle i[n]=A_J\exp(j2\pi f_JnT_s)$`. Of course, labeling and referencing of the equation will also not be possible, i'm afraid.

Comment: you have not shown a usable example but I would guess that you have an `equation `in ` `c` column, that can not work a `c` column is a one line construct like `\mbox` so can not contain display material like `equation`. Either use inline math `$...$` or use a `p` column

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that's right. For transparency's sake, i edited my comment accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The tabular code can be simplified if, instead of using `\begin{equation)` to create an equation number and a label, you define a special label to insert consecutive numbers and also to be able to refer to a specific cell in the table.

Taken from [Can I refer to cells in a tabular?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81973/can-i-refer-to-cells-in-a-tabular)

[image: y]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

%% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81973/can-i-refer-to-cells-in-a-tabular
\newcounter{spcounter}\renewcommand{\thespcounter}{\arabic{spcounter}}
\newcommand{\speciallabel}[1]{%          >>>> \speciallabel{<label>}
\hfill\refstepcounter{spcounter}(\thespcounter)\label{#1}%
}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}

\begin{document}
    
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt} 
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2} % Default value: 1
    \begin{table}[h]
        \small
        \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|C|c|c|}
            \hline
            Class&Type&Baseband model&Design parameters\\
            \hline
            I&CW&   $i[n]=A_J\exp(j2\pi f_JnT_s)\qquad$\speciallabel{eq:jammer_CW} % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            &$A_{J}$, $f_{J}$ \\[1ex]
            \hline
            II&Single Chirp& $i[n] = A_{J}\exp(j2\pi T_{s}\sum_{j=0}^{n}f_{J}[j])\qquad$\speciallabel{eq:jammer_ST} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            &$A_{J}$, $T_{sweep}$, $\Delta f$ \\[1ex]
            \hline
            II&Pulsed Jammer&Equation (\ref{eq:jammer_ST}) with $\Delta f > BW$&$A_{J}$, $T_{sweep}$, $\Delta f$\\[1ex]
            \hline
        \end{tabularx}
        \caption{Classification of the implemented jamming baseband signal models, according to equations (\ref{eq:jammer_CW}) and (\ref{eq:jammer_ST}).}
        \label{tab:signalmodels}
    \end{table} 
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `amsmath`, `makecell` and `tabullarx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize \centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
    \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c |C{0.6}
                                |C{1.8}
                                |C{0.6}|
                            }
    \Xhline{1pt}
Class   & Type  & {Baseband model}
                    & {Design   parameters}                     \\
    \Xhline{0.6pt}
                    I   & CW
                            &   \begin{gather}\label{eq:jammer_CW}
                        i[n] = A_J\exp(j2\pi f_JnT_s)
                                \end{gather}
                            & $A_{J}$, $f_{J}$                          \\
    \hline
    II  & Single Chirp
                &   \begin{equation}\label{eq:jammer_ST}
                i[n] = A_{J}\exp(j2\pi T_{s}\sum_{j=0}^{n}f_{J}[j])
                    \end{equation}
                    & $A_{J}$, $T_\mathrm{sweep}$, $\Delta f$   \\
    \hline
    III & Pulsed Jammer
                &   Equation \eqref{eq:jammer_ST} with $\Delta f>BW$
                    & $A_{J}$, $T_\mathrm{sweep}$, $\Delta f$\\[1ex]
    \Xhline{1pt}
        \end{tabularx}
\caption{Classification of the implemented jamming baseband signal models,n according to equations \eqref{eq:jammer_CW} and \eqref{eq:jammer_ST}.}
\label{tab:signalmodels}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]